# 2 dimensional interpolation problem

Tags: python, scipy

I have DATA on x and y axes and the output is on z

for example

```
y = 10
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
z = [2.3,3.4,5.6,7.8,9.6,11.2]

y = 20 
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
z = [4.3,5.4,7.6,9.8,11.6,13.2]

y = 30 
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
z = [6.3,7.4,8.6,10.8,13.6,15.2]
```

how can i find the value of z when  y = 15  x = 3.5

I was trying to use scipy but i am very new at it

Thanks a lot for the help

vibhor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

scipy.interpolate.bisplrep

Reference:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.bisplrep.html

```
import scipy
import math
import numpy
from scipy import interpolate


x= [1,2,3,4,5,6]
y= [10,20,30]

Y = numpy.array([[i]*len(x) for i in y])
X = numpy.array([x for i in y])
Z = numpy.array([[2.3,3.4,5.6,7.8,9.6,11.2],
                 [4.3,5.4,7.6,9.8,11.6,13.2],
                 [6.3,7.4,8.6,10.8,13.6,15.2]]) 

tck = interpolate.bisplrep(X,Y,Z)
print interpolate.bisplev(3.5,15,tck) 


7.84921875
```

**EDIT:**

Upper solution does not give you perfect fit. 
check

```
print interpolate.bisplev(x,y,tck)

[[  2.2531746    4.2531746    6.39603175]
 [  3.54126984   5.54126984   7.11269841]
 [  5.5031746    7.5031746    8.78888889]
 [  7.71111111   9.71111111  10.9968254 ]
 [  9.73730159  11.73730159  13.30873016]
 [ 11.15396825  13.15396825  15.2968254 ]]
```

to overcome this interpolate whit polyinomials of 5rd degree in x and 2nd degree in y direction

```
tck = interpolate.bisplrep(X,Y,Z,kx=5,ky=2)
print interpolate.bisplev(x,y,tck) 

[[  2.3   4.3   6.3]
 [  3.4   5.4   7.4]
 [  5.6   7.6   8.6]
 [  7.8   9.8  10.8]
 [  9.6  11.6  13.6]
 [ 11.2  13.2  15.2]]
```

This yield

```
print interpolate.bisplev(3.5,15,tck)

7.88671875
```

**Plotting:**
reference http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/mplot3d/surface3d_demo.html

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z,rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.jet)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hey Thanks I think this works perfectly 
One more question how can i plot them in X Y z axes

Comment: Note that scipy.interpolate.* (FITPACK) splines may not interpolate,
i.e. may not go through the input data; see smoothness parameter s.
Imho FITPACK has more power than doc, so start simple (Martelli): kx=ky=1, s=0.

Answer (score 1):

Given (not as Python code, since the second assignment would obliterate the first in each case, of course;-):

```
y = 10
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
z = [2.3,3.4,5.6,7.8,9.6,11.2]

y = 20 
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
z = [4.3,5.4,7.6,9.8,11.6,13.2]
```

you ask: "how can i find the value of z when y = 15 x = 3.5"?

Since you're looking at a point exactly equidistant in both x and y from the given "grid", you just take the midpoint between the grid values (if you had values not equidistant, you'd take a proportional midpoint, see later).  So for y=10, the z values for x 3 and 4 are 5.6 and 7.8, so for x 3.5 you estimate their midpoint, 6.7; and similarly for y=20 you estimate the midpoint between 7.6 and 9.8, i.e., 8.7.  Finally, since you have y=15, the midpoint between 6.7 and 8.7 is your final interpolated value for z: 7.7.

Say you had y=13 and x=3.8 instead.  Then for x you'd take the values 80% of the way, i.e.:

- for y=10, 0.2*5.6+0.8*7.8 -> 7.36
- for y=20, 0.2*7.6+0.8*9.8 -> 9.46

Now you want the z 30% of the way between these, 0.3*7.36 + 0.7*9.46 -> 8.83, that's z.

This is **linear interpolation**, and it's really very simple.  Do you want to compute it by hand, or find routines that do it for you (given e.g. `numpy` arrays as "the grids")?  Even in the latter case, I hope this "manual" explanation (showing what you're doing in the most elementary of arithmetical terms) can help you understand what you're doing...;-).

There are more advanced forms of interpolation, of course -- do you need those, or does linear interpolation suffice for your use case?

Comment: ya thanks i got what you are saying ... 
i will be needing the routines because I just gave an example in my question 
in my collected data
my y values go from 10 .... 300 steps of 10 
my x values goes 1 ... 20
and similarly 20 different z values for each of y value

so i was thinking if there is a ways to interpolate or extrapolate the x and y values

Answer (score 0):

I would say just take the average of the values around it.  So if you need X=3.5 and Y=15 (3.5,15), you average (3,10), (3,20), (4,10) and (4,20).  Since I have no idea what the data is you are dealing with, I am not sure if the exact proximity would matter - in which case you can just stick w/the average - or if you need to do some sort of inverse distance weighting.