# Set a limitation on the returning value and number of decimals in Python

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import itertools
xs = [0.15, 0.35, 0.50, 0.67, 0.80]
ys = [0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05]
z =  [0.60, 0.70, 0.80, 0.90, 1.00]
```

I have this code to return the value of Z:

```
tck = interpolate.bisplrep(x, y, z, s=0)
def givemeZ(x,y):
    return interpolate.bisplev(x,y,tck),'%0.5f'
```

1. How can I put a limitation on the returning value that doesnt come
   with a value higher than 1? If its higher than 1, the code will
   reject it..
2. To give me 5 decimals after the zero, because its returning the
   value+,`'%0.5f'`?

I appreciate all the help!

Comment: 1) what do you want to get instead (if value is > 1)?
2) you are using formatting incorrectly. Try `return '{:.5f}'.format(interpolate.bisplev(x,y,tck))`

Comment: This works for the decimals, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
tck = interpolate.bisplrep(x, y, z, s=0)
def givemeZ(x,y):
    result = interpolate.bisplev(x,y,tck)
    return '{:.5f}'.format(min(1.0, result))
```

The returned result is *capped by 1.0*. It will never be bigger.

Comment: return '{:.5f}'.format(min(1.0, res))
NameError: name 'res' is not defined
It gives me this error

Comment: @user8670370 it was a typo. Try again

Answer (score 0):

You could return another value and check for it

```
tck = interpolate.bisplrep(x, y, z, s=0)
def givemeZ(x,y):
    rtr = interpolate.bisplev(x,y,tck),'%0.5f'
    return round(rtr, 5) if rtr <= 1 else None
z = givemeZ(x,y)
if z is None:
    print "Z is greater than 1!"
    quit() # or other error handling
```

This checks if the return value, `rtr`, is less than or equal to one, if so it'll return the rounded value, otherwise it returns `None`. Then you can check for `None` and deal with it however you're handling errors.

Comment: `rtr` is a `tuple` due to the way it is defined and you cannot do `round()` on a `tuple`

Comment: Thanks, I'm not familiar with the function. Curiously, though, this example shows otherwise. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977467/2-dimensional-interpolation-problem

I'll update my answer with both forms though.

Comment: I do not see `round()` performed on any `tuple` there. Did you try running your code?